Flutter go_router redirects to / on state change when it should not redirect at all
I have this router:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:horizon/providers/user.dart';
import 'package:horizon/screens/add_post.dart';
import 'package:horizon/screens/error.dart';
import 'package:horizon/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:horizon/screens/loading.dart';
import 'package:horizon/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:horizon/screens/moderation.dart';
import 'package:horizon/screens/settings.dart';

final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
GoRouter? _previousRouter;

final routerProvider = Provider((ref) {
  final user = ref.watch(userStateProvider).currentUser;

  final newRouter = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    initialLocation:
        _previousRouter?.routerDelegate.currentConfiguration.fullPath,
    errorBuilder: (context, state) =>
        ErrorScreen(error: state.error?.message ?? 'An error occurred'),
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/login',
        builder: (context, state) => const LoginScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/settings',
        builder: (context, state) => const SettingsScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/loading',
        builder: (context, state) => const LoadingScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/add_post',
        builder: (context, state) => const AddPostScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/moderation',
        builder: (context, state) => const ModerationScreen(),
      ),
    ],
    redirect: (context, state) {
      final loggingIn = state.uri.toString() == '/login';
      final loading = state.uri.toString() == '/loading';

      // If user is not logged in, redirect to login unless already on login page
      if (user == null) {
        return loggingIn ? null : '/login';
      }

      // If user UID is "0", redirect to loading unless already on loading page
      if (user.uid == "loading") {
        return loading ? null : '/loading';
      }

      // If user is logged in and on login page, redirect to home
      if ((loggingIn || loading) && user.name != null && user.email != null) {
        print("Redirecting to home");
        return '/';
      }

      // Default: do not redirect if already signed in
      print("Returning null, state.uri: ${state.uri}");
      return null;
    },
  );
  _previousRouter = newRouter;
  print(
      "Print before return: ${_previousRouter?.routerDelegate.currentConfiguration.fullPath}");

  return newRouter;
});

I am using go router to watch my riverpod provider for auth changes. it works great, unless I change the current user on another page. For example, changing the user name on the settings page. In this case, it redirects to the home page (/).
Some of the print outputs:
Print before return: 
When I first navigate to the settings page, Returning null, state.uri: /settings prints. This seems odd, because just navigating doesn't change the user.
Once I update the user on the settings page, Returning null, state.uri: / prints.
